# iReports: Creating charts using crosstab "total variables"?

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

Is it possible to use variables ,that are defined in crosstab like total measure variables etc
in the formation of charts in iReports...

Like I need chart of percentage of certain measure which in crosstab I calculated using total variable. How to do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding for reporting with iReports, it is not possible to use those variables that are defined in the crosstab in charts. Crosstab is a seperated component from charts. All the variable that are defined in the crosstab are defined in the scope of the Crosstab only.

For this fix I have to modify by query. Now they are somewhat complex I have used Common table expressions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx to get all the desired fields in my query only and used them directly in the iReports charts.

Hope this helps..